# Passing const pointers to const by reference in functions

Tags: c++

I am playing a bit around with arrays and passing pointers by reference to functions. Consider as an example the following code:

```cpp
#include<iostream>

void test_fn(const int* const &i){
    std::cout<<*i<<std::endl;
}

int main(){
    int arr_1[5] {1, 3, 6, 4, 5};
    int *int_ptr1 {nullptr};
    int_ptr1=arr_1;
    test_fn(int_ptr1);

    return 0;
}
```

This code runs properly.

However, if I amend the definition of the `test_fn` to read:

```cpp
void test_fn(const int* &i){
    std::cout<<*i<<std::endl;
}
```

I get the following error:

> cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'const int*&' to an rvalue of type 'const int*'

My question is: Why is this an issue in the second example but not in the first, where the only difference is that the pointer is being passed as a const pointer?

Comment: Why a C-style array and not a `std::array`??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the 2nd example, the function takes a reference to a **non-const** `const int*` pointer, but you are giving it an `int*` pointer instead.  Because the pointer is non-const, the reference cannot be bound to a temporary `const int*` variable created by the compiler to implicitly convert from `int*` to `const int*`. The reference requires a non-const `const int*` variable at the call site, so you would have to explicitly declare `int_ptr1` as `const int*` instead of `int*`:

```cpp
const int *int_ptr1 = arr_1;
```

In the 1st example, the function takes a reference to a **const** `const int*` pointer.  Since the pointer is const, the compiler can implicitly convert from `int*` to `const int*` and store the result in a temporary variable, and then bind the reference to that temporary.

Comment: I'm not sure which object you are referring to when you say *"it cannot be bound to a temporary variable created by the compiler"*. Is this a hypothetical variable? Edit : Nevermind, the result of the implicit conversion is the rvalue.